# Replace column values in a 2d array using a flat array of replacement values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, mapping

I have a two-dimensional array of this format:

```
$oldArr = [
    0 => [
        "color" => "red",
        "shape" => "circle",
        "size" => "small",
    ],
    1 => [
        "color" => "green",
        "shape" => "square",
        "size" => "large",
    ],
    2 => [
        "color" => "yellow",
        "shape" => "triangle",
        "size" => "large",
    ],
];
```

And a one-dimensional array of this format:

```
$newVals = [
    0 => "large",
    1 => "large",
    2 => "small",
];
```

I'm attempting to use `str_replace()` to iterate through each `"size"` value in `$oldArr`, and replace it with the value in `$newVals` that matches its position. Since these arrays will always have the same number of top-level key-value pairs, I'm basically trying to take `$newVals` and map it onto each `$oldArr["size"]` value. The end result should be

```
$newArr = [
    0 => [
        "color" => "red",
        "shape" => "circle",
        "size" => "large",
    ],
    1 => [
        "color" => "green",
        "shape" => "square",
        "size" => "large",
    ],
    2 => [
        "color" => "yellow",
        "shape" => "triangle",
        "size" => "small",
    ],
];
```

Can anyone recommend the best way to go about this? I've attempted a `str_replace` in a foreach loop, but it hasn't worked:

```
foreach($oldArr as $entity):

    str_replace($entity['size'], $newVals, $entity);

endforeach;
```

Comment: Kind of, sort of related: [Replace multidimensional array values with one-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72826896/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and loop through both arrays at once and instead of using the size value of your original array, you just use the new one, e.g.

```
$result = array_map(function($old, $new){
    return ["color" => $old["color"], "shape" => $old["shape"], "size" => $new];
}, $oldArr, $newVals);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
<?php

$oldArr = [
    0 => [
        "color" => "red",
        "shape" => "circle",
        "size" => "small",
    ],
    1 => [
        "color" => "green",
        "shape" => "square",
        "size" => "large",
    ],
    2 => [
        "color" => "yellow",
        "shape" => "triangle",
        "size" => "large",
    ],
];


$newVals = [
    0 => "large",
    1 => "large",
    2 => "small",
];

$newArr = array();
foreach($oldArr as $key => $entity){
    $newEntity = $entity;
    $newEntity['size'] = $newVals[$key];
    $newArr[$key] = $newEntity;
}

var_dump($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_walk()` modifying the original array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/to4bl))

```
array_walk(
    $oldArr,
    fn(&$row, $i) => $row['size'] = $newVals[$i]
);
var_export($oldArr);
```

---

`foreach()` modifying the original array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6evSg))

```
foreach ($oldArr as $i => ['size' => &$size]) {
    $size = $newVals[$i];
}
var_export($oldArr);
```

---

`foreach()` to produce a new array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bKrbB))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($oldArr as $i => $row) {
    $row['size'] = $newVals[$i];
    $result[] = $row;
}
var_export($result);
```

---

`array_map()` to synchronously iterate both arrays and avoid declaring a result array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/75NX3))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row, $size) => array_replace($row, ['size' => $size]),
        $oldArr,
        $newVals
    )
);
```

*Because the rows to be joined contain associative/non-numeric keys, `array_merge()` and `array_replace()` behave identically.  The array union operator (`+`) can not be used for this task because it retains the left side elements where both payloads contain the same key -- in other words, there would be no change.

---

`array_replace_recursive()` after mutating the new values into a 2d array: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/oFMJg))

```
var_export(
    array_replace_recursive(
        $oldArr,
        array_map(fn($size) => ['size' => $size], $newVals)
    )
);
```