# Replace multidimensional array values with one-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to change the values in one multidimensional array if a corresponding key is found in another flat, associative array.

I have these two arrays:

```
$full = [
    'Cars' => [
         'Volvo' => 0,
         'Mercedes' => 0,
         'BMW' => 0,
         'Audi' => 0
    ],
    'Motorcycle' => [
        'Ducati' => 0,
        'Honda' => 0,
        'Suzuki' => 0,
        'KTM' => 0
    ]
];

$semi = [
    'Volvo' => 1,
    'Audi' => 1
];
```

I want the array to look like this:

```
Array
(
    [Cars] => Array
        (
            [Volvo] => 1
            [Mercedes] => 0
            [BMW] => 0
            [Audi] => 1
        )

    [Motorcycle] => Array
        (
            [Ducati] => 0
            [Honda] => 0
            [Suzuki] => 0
            [KTM] => 0
        )
)
```

I get the $semi array back from my input field and want to merge it into $full to save it into my database.

I already tried `array_replace()` like:

```
$replaced = array_replace($full, $semi);
```

Comment: What if... Honda is both a car and a motorcycle, how would you know where to add it?

Comment: Those are just dummy values, normally, we have distinct values. Just changed it for the question here

Comment: The problem with accepting an answer too quickly is that you decrease the incentive for other contributor to add alternative answers.  Please always present array data as var_export so that contributors can instantly use your data in their sandboxes.  Now I have to waste my time retyping your input on my phone before I can test my suggested code.

Comment: @mickmackusa my bad, sorry

Comment: This might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329). If you explain how your database table is configured, we may be able to avoid this whole task and just send this user-supplied data directly to your table with a well-crafted UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop your `$semi` array and check if it exists in one of `$full` arrays, then add to it:

```php
foreach ($semi as $semiItem => $semiValue) {
    foreach ($full as &$fullItems) {
        if (isset($fullItems[$semiItem])) {
            $fullItems[$semiItem] = $semiValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it also possible to set all other values = 0 that are not in the $semi array?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to visit "leafnodes", it will be very direct to iterate and modify the full array with `array_walk_recursive()`.

Modern "arrow function" syntax allows access to the semi array without writing `use()`.

This approach makes absolutely no iterated function calls.  It modifies `$v` by reference (`&$v`), uses the "addition assignment" combined operator (`+=`), and the null coalescing opetator (`??`) to conditionally increase values in the full array which are found in the semi array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/iUcWh))

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $full,
    fn(&$v, $k) => $v += $semi[$k] ?? 0
);

var_export($full);
```

---

Not using `array_walk_recursive()` would necessitate using nested loops to increase qualifying manufacturers.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IoHmj))

```
foreach ($full as &$manufacturers) {
    foreach ($manufacturers as $m => &$count) {
        $count += $semi[$m] ?? 0;
    }
}
var_export($full);
```

Comment: If you are merely overwriting the counts (not adding them), you can use `=` instead of `+=`.